# How to Read a png File Stored Within an Exported jar in Eclipse

Tags: java, jar, inputstream, bufferedreader

I have watched several videos and visited every stackoverflow thread I could find about reading files from within a jar and none of the methods I have found worked for me.

My most recent attempt was building a ResourceLoader class and it worked just fine in the ide but, when I exported it to a runnable jar it doesn't seem to be able to find the files.

Here is the ResourceLoader class

```
public final class ResourceLoader {

    public static InputStream load(String path) {
        InputStream input = ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
        if(input==null) {
            input = ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(File.separator+path);
        }
        return input;
    }

}
```

My png files are stored in a folder named "textures" and that folder is inside a src folder named "res"

Comment: `File.separator+path` ← Never do that.  The argument to getResource and getResourceAsStream is actually a relative URL and should **always** use forward slashes (`/`) on all platforms.  You probably want `ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/textures/image.png")`.  It is considered good practice to place application resources in the same package as the class that loads them, which allows you write shorter calls like `ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("image.png")`.  When in doubt, examine the contents of your .jar file.

Comment: After doing as you suggested it works but, I have to put the literal path to the wanted resource. Is there a way to add all the png files found in a folder?

Comment: *It is considered good practice to place application resources in the same package as the class that loads them* Not sure about that. For one thing, that would potentially leave resources peppered all over your package tree, instead of in one logical place, like .... `res` I would say, group your resources logically, starting at *one* resource root. *Is there a way to add all the png files found in a folder?* No. Not without hacky methods. What is your use case for doing that?

Comment: “Is there a way to add all the png files found in a folder?”  No.  Some people may suggest ways to do it, but those illicit methods *will* fail eventually.  The good news is that it doesn’t matter;  you already know what files are in your project, so you can keep a hard-coded list of them in your application.

Comment: @g00se They don’t get peppered all over.  Images used by a MainWindow class go in the same package as that class.  Images used by a LoginWindow class go in the same package as that class.  The images are no more scattered than the application classes themselves.  But most importantly… resources belong in packages for the same reason classes belong in packages:  to greatly reduce the possibility of collisions with other libraries on the classpath.  Multiple libraries with a `/icon.png` resource is not a good thing.

Comment: I ended up putting a text file in the resource folder that contains the names of all the png files I want to load, thanks for all the advice.